# Missing helper path when doing rake routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I wanted to do like `http://domain:3000/users/id/edit/details`. I've already create a new action under app>views>users>details.html.erb. Also in UsersController i put:

```
def details
  ....
end
```

when I run `rake routes`, I got missing Helper Path/Url on the left side for GET, /users/:id/edit/details(.:format), Users#Details.

Also in routes.rb, I've:

```
resources :users
```

I try to insert:

```
match "users/:id/edit/details", to: 'users#details', via: 'get'
```

but stil didnt solve my problem. Please help me!

Comment: what do you get when you run `rake routes`?

Comment: Why not use the 'edit' action and view?  That's what is created by the resources :users line...

Comment: @dax i got empty path for /users/:id/edit/details(.:format)

Comment: @Swards because i use credential for basic form (username, email, password, confirm password) but for above statement is for advance form (f.name, l.name, phone number, nationality and etc)

Comment: I see - can they both PUT to the same update method? (you'd need to conditionally redirect on error or success).  Either way, you'd want to make a new GET method in your route file.  I'll add an answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In routes, you'd want to do this:

```
resources :users do
  get :details
end
```

In this, you'd have the advance form.  The url for this will be

```
/users/:id/details/
```

Check rake routes to see what's in there.

You may need another update method (the form post action) to handle the advanced form

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called nested resources

```
resources :users do
  resources :details
end
```

Take a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources for more info

Comment: Still didnt solve my prove.. or is this normal?
1. rake routes [before](http://i.imgur.com/WgNfH7D.png)
2. rake routes [after](http://i.imgur.com/faeEFpE.png)

it show :user_id which is i dont know where it come from.

Comment: user_id is the id of the user whose details you are looking/editing/deleting. If you wanted to generate the path you could do ( I think ) `user_detail_path(@user, @detail)`